# How to create box plot from pandas object using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I read data into `pandas` object and then I want to create a box plot using `matplotlib` (not `pandas.boxplot()`). This is just for learning purposes. This is my code, in which `myData['MyColumn']` fails.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

myData = pd.read_csv('data/myData.csv')

plt.boxplot(myData['MyColumn'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: For your example with one column, just convert the pandas series `myData['MyColumn']` into a list

Comment: @joaquin: How can I do this? Could you give an example?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? That worked just fine (on my data) for me. 
As for the suggestion from @joaquin, I believe he means trying this:
`plt.boxplot(myData['MyColumn'].values)`

Comment: @Zaphod: Thanks, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with fake data. Check the type of the data you're trying to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
myData = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=['MyColumn', 'blah'])
plt.boxplot(myData['MyColumn'])
plt.show()
```